# How to properly return HttpStatus in Mono<ResponseEntity>?

Tags: spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have an api which returns some `HttpStatus` code. And based on the code the gatekeeper will perform some action. Following is just a skeleton of the API.

```
@GetMapping("/globalretry")
public Mono<ResponseEntity> testGlobalRetryFilter(@RequestParam(name = "code") int code) {
    Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    map.put("code", code);
    switch (code) {
        case 200:
            map.put("status", "SUCCESS");
            break;
        case 504:
            map.put("status", "RETRY: GATEWAY_TIMEOUT");
            break;
        default:
            map.put("status", "BAD_REQUEST");
            break;
    }
    return Mono.just(new ResponseEntity(map, HttpStatus.valueOf(code)));
}
```

Now the problem is , if I return the response code in such way, then spring is not able to identify the status code from `Mono<ResponseEntity>`. Can any body help me on how to return the `statuscode` in a way thus spring can identify the response's status code

Comment: ResponseEntity has a builder function which you can pass a 'int' and it was do all your work for you ... ResponseEntity.status(code).build() is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own object plus in construct you have too add HTTP_STATUS
example:

```
new ResponseEntity<>(new ErrorResponse(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, LOGIN_NOT_UNIQUE_MSG), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
```

---

```
public class ErrorResponse {
    private HttpStatus status;
    private int code;
    private String message;

    public ErrorResponse(HttpStatus status, String message) {
        this.message = message;
        this.status = status;
        this.code = status.value();
    }
}
```